# AD Sync includes the ability to select a user I want to block

Tags: site-collection, user-profile-service, active-directory-import

I have created a sync connection to my AD forest, and I'm selecting very specific OU's to sync.

This means that my forest of 6'500 users is actually only synching 360 - which is exactly what I need.

The problem however, is that I do not sync user "Joe Bloggs" with the AD import. I don't want "Joe" to be able to see my site.

However, if I go to the site, and use the people picker, I can see select him if I start to type in his name.

Additionally, if I put in the "Everyone" user, he can access the site as well.

How do I go about ensuring that only the OU's I've synched are able to see the site (either as users, or via the "Everyone" option)?

The reason for this, is that we have sets of users that must not have access to the portal. They are large sets of users, so adding people manually would be time consuming.

I was hoping that a specific set of OU's, combined with "Everyone" would block them out (as they are not being synched in the first place).

Edit: 29/10/2015

I have also tried this trick to restrict the people picker

```
    Set-SPSite -Identity "http://example.com" -UserAccountDirectoryPath "OU=UserSet,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=eu,DC=foo,DC=domain,DC=COM"
```

This means the people picker only shows me users from Accounts > Users > UserSet.

Works perfectly, I can't add any users that I don't want - however, adding in "Eveyone" still gives "Jo Bloggs" access.

I can't fathom out how I can request that only the user profile directory is used.

Comment: Permissions for the site is not bound to what you sync! And you will find no easy way to couple those two. The way to go is probably to create a group in your AD containing only the users that you sync and then give permissions on your site to this group only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict OU access using the `Set-SPSite` cmdlet with the `-UserAccountDirectoryPath` param but as with any LDAP filter this is limited to one OU.

You can change the people picker settings using PS:

```
 $wapp = Get-SPWebApplication
 $wapp.PeoplePickerSettings
```

This gives you access to `ActiveDirectoryCustomQuery` and `ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter` that will apply to the web app rather than the site.

Finally you could use a variety of this solution [Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245/people-picker-and-fltering-by-certain-ad-groups) proposed for MOSS but will still work.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Set-SPSite is only going to restrict what I see on the people picker? Even if I have "Everyone" added, the user I wish to exclude is still going to be pulled in. And am I correct in thinking that the people picker settings just relate to what I can see, not actual access?

Comment: Yes indeed, unfortunately none of the above will do exactly what you want but they do give you some options... The link to the other Stack Exchange question is about as close as you are going to get.

Comment: Super, thanks - looks like it's the security group route for this. Thanks again!